# setting alerts only when ema changes color

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to add alerts only when the color changes from red to green for buy, and green to red for sell, but it's giving me alerts on every single candle that's red and green. What should I do to make it so that it only gives alert when the color changes?

```
//@version=2

study(title="HMA Colored", overlay=true)

func_hma(style, length)=>

    return = wma((2 * wma(style, length / 2)) - wma(style, length), round(sqrt(length)))

shortPeriod = input(100, title="HMA")

shortHMA = func_hma(close, shortPeriod)
current = shortHMA[0]
prev = shortHMA[1]

long= current > prev
short= current < prev

plotshape(long, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny, title="buy" )
plotshape(short, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, title="sell")
plot(shortHMA, color=current > prev ? green : red, linewidth=2, title="HMA")
alertcondition(long, title="Buy",  message="green buy")
alertcondition(sell, title="Sell", message="red sell")
```

Answer (score -1):

`long` and `short` variables will be `true` for multiple bars. You need to check if it is a new long or new short and use it in your alert condition.

```
new_long = not long[1] and long
new_short = not short[1] and short

plotshape(new_long, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny, title="buy" )
plotshape(new_short, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, title="sell")
plot(shortHMA, color=current > prev ? green : red, linewidth=2, title="HMA")
alertcondition(new_long, title="Buy",  message="green buy")
alertcondition(new_short, title="Sell", message="red sell")
```